# Optimizing the edge lengths of a graph (again)

Tags: graphs-and-networks, mathematical-optimization

This is a follow up to my previous question posted [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230523/optimizing-the-edge-lengths-of-a-graph)

The code below is from the answer provided [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/230741/58343)

```
Clear[solution3d];
solution3d[uedges_, edgeweight_] := 
 Module[{ew, graph, dmat, newcoords, vcoords3, newLayout, vars, 
   weights, objective, min, vals, newercoords, xyz, 
   DistanceMatrixDimensionReduce}, 
  ew = KeyMap[UndirectedEdge @@ # &, edgeweight];
  graph = 
   Graph3D[Keys[ew], EdgeWeight -> Normal[ew], 
    VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
    EdgeLabels -> {e_ :> Placed["EdgeWeight", Center]}, 
    VertexSize -> .3, VertexStyle -> Red];
  dmat = GraphDistanceMatrix[graph];
  DistanceMatrixDimensionReduce[(dmat_)?MatrixQ, dim_ : 3] := 
   With[{len = Length[dmat]}, 
    Module[{diffs, dist2mat, onevec, hmat, bmat, uu, ww, vv}, 
      onevec = ConstantArray[{1}, len];
      hmat = IdentityMatrix[len] - onevec.Transpose[onevec]/len;
      dist2mat = -dmat/2;
      bmat = hmat.dist2mat.hmat; {uu, ww, vv} = 
       SingularValueDecomposition[bmat, dim]; uu.Sqrt[ww]] /; 
     dim <= Length[dmat[[1]]] && MatchQ[Flatten[dmat], {_Real ..}]];
  newcoords = DistanceMatrixDimensionReduce[dmat];
  newLayout = 
   Graph[Keys[ew], VertexCoordinates -> newcoords, EdgeWeight -> ew, 
    VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
    EdgeLabels -> {e_ :> Placed["EdgeWeight", Center]}, 
    VertexSize -> .3, VertexStyle -> Red];
  vars = Array[xyz, {VertexCount[graph], 3}];
  weights = Normal[WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[graph]];
  objective = 
   Sum[If[weights[[i, j]] > 
      0, ((vars[[i]] - vars[[j]]).(vars[[i]] - vars[[j]]) - 
        weights[[i, j]]^2)^2, 0], {i, Length[weights] - 1}, {j, i + 1,
      Length[weights]}];
  {min, vals} = 
   Quiet@FindMinimum[objective, 
     Flatten[MapThread[List, {vars, newcoords}, 2], 1]];
  newercoords = vars /. vals;
  vcoords3 = MapIndexed[#2[[1]] -> # &, newercoords];
  newLayout = 
   Graph3D[Keys[ew], VertexCoordinates -> vcoords3, EdgeWeight -> ew, 
    VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
    EdgeLabels -> {e_ :> Placed["EdgeWeight", Center]}, 
    VertexSize -> .3, VertexStyle -> Red];
  Return[<|"newcoords" -> newcoords, "error" -> min|>]]
```

For the `edges` and `ew` specified below the code works well for repositioning the nodes of the network
to meet the distance requirements provided as edge weights.To create a layout that meets the distance requirements, an inital layout, which created using multidimensional scaling, is used for optimization via FindMinimum.

```
edges = {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 5}, {2, 6}, {5, 6}, {3, 4}, {3, 
     7}, {6, 7}, {7, 8}, {2, 9}};
 ew = <|{1, 2} -> 49.6, {1, 3} -> 74.4, {1, 4} -> 49.6, {2, 5} -> 
     37.2, {2, 6} -> 74.4, {5, 6} -> 49.6, {3, 4} -> 37.2, {3, 7} -> 
     24.8, {6, 7} -> 62, {7, 8} -> 37.2, {2, 9} -> 24.8|>;
result = solution3d[edges, ew]
Print[result];
```

But the error for the following input (added externally due to the limitation in characters that can be added here)  is really large. I'd like to know if there are other methods to create better initial layouts that can be supplied to FindMinimum.

Error returned from the code for the below edges and ew is error->4.53978*10^11.

[edges, ew](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yBDoqpTog9Oz2s5KPLXsujs4tuMj3Ww5/view?usp=sharing) (also shared [here](https://github.com/DeepaMahm/misc/blob/master/ip.txt))

Comment: Couldn't you just make the edges in the `Graph3D` thinner tubes?

Comment: @flinty I'm sorry, I started the bounty in the wrong post by mistake. I have updated the right question here. The question for which you have commented is [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/237166/scaling-the-edge-length-of-a-graph-to-be-equal-to-edge-weight-for-3d-graphs). Thank you