# Optimizing the edge lengths of a graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks, mathematical-optimization

This is a follow up to my question posted [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/220334/scaling-the-edge-length-of-a-graph-to-be-equal-to-edge-weight)

The following code scales the edge lengths of a graph to be equal to edge weights

```
edges = {1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 3, 1 <-> 4, 2 <-> 5, 2 <-> 6, 5 <-> 6, 
   3 <-> 4, 3 <-> 7, 6 <-> 7, 7 <-> 8, 2 <-> 9};

vd = {{75., 25., 0}, {115., 45., 0}, {10., 5., 0}, {45., 0, 0}, 
  {90., 60., 0}, {45., 55., 0}, {0, 25., 0}, {10., 50., 0}, {115.,  25.,0}};

vl = Range[Length@vd];

vcoords = MapIndexed[#2[[1]] -> # &, vd];
ew = {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2 -> 49.6, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 3 -> 74.4, 
 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 4 -> 49.6, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 5 -> 37.2, 
 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 6 -> 74.4, 5 \[UndirectedEdge] 6 -> 49.6, 
 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 4 -> 37.2, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 7 -> 24.8, 
 6 \[UndirectedEdge] 7 -> 62, 7 \[UndirectedEdge] 8 -> 37.2, 
 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 9 -> 24.8}

g3d = Graph3D[vl, edges, VertexCoordinates -> vcoords, 
  EdgeWeight -> ew, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
  EdgeLabels -> {e_ :> Placed["EdgeWeight", Center]}, 
  VertexSize -> .3, VertexStyle -> Red]
vars3d = Array[Through[{x, y, z}@#] &, Length @ vd];

λ = 1/100.;

obj3d = Total[(Norm[vars3d[[First@#]] - vars3d[[Last@#]]] - # /. ew)^2 & /@ 
  EdgeList[g3d]] +  λ Total[Norm /@ (vars3d - vd)];

lbnd = 0;
ubnd = 500;

solution3d = Last@Minimize[{obj3d, And @@ Thread[lbnd <= Join @@ vars3d <= ubnd]}, 
    Join @@ vars3d];

edgeLengths3d = # -> Norm[vars3d[[First@#]] - vars3d[[Last@#]]] /. 
     solution3d & /@ EdgeList[g3d];

Grid[Prepend[{#, # /. ew, # /. edgeLengths3d} & /@ 
   EdgeList[g3d], {"edge", "EdgeWeight", "Edge Length"}], 
 Dividers -> All]
```

Using the above code, optimization was successful i.e the coordinates of the nodes are positioned in such a way that the edge lengths are equal to edge weights specified by the user. However, I tried a bigger graph network (check [notebook](https://github.com/DeepaMahm/misc/blob/master/check.nb)) and in the result obtained after optimization, the edge lengths of some of the edges in the graph are not equal to the user-defined edge weights.

Setting $\lambda$ = 0, I tried for changing the bounds set for optimization
lbnd = 0; ubnd = 5000;
and
lbnd = -500; ubnd = 500;

For both the runs, the edge lengths of some of the edges in the graph are not equal to the user-defined edge weights. Also, the optimization task runs for a long duration. I'm not sure how to speed it up.

I'd like to know if there are better ways of optimizing the edge lengths or if there are other suggestions I will be happy to try.

EDIT:
The answer posted below addresses one-half of the issue posted above. It helps in solving the optimization problem faster but I'm still facing issues while trying to optimize large networks. For instance, as pointed out by @Szabolcs sometimes the triangle inequality isn't obeyed by the edge-weights of the corresponding edges that form a triangle. This results in a mismatch in the user-defined edge-weights and the edge-weights computed after optimization. I am still looking for ways that will help in finding out why such mismatches occur for other edges that don't form a triangle. This will help me in identifying those edges and re-compute the user-defined edge weights.

Comment: Why do you expect that every weighted graph can be isometrically embedded into Euclidean space?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I'm sorry, I couldn't completely understand. Could you please explain a bit?

Comment: This is what I said when you started asking these questions originally. What you want to do is simply not possible in general, for any graph and any weights. I checked your example, and it does not satisfy the triangle inequality. Consider the triangle `{110, 34, 102}` with weights `{24.8, 62., 24.8}`.

Comment: Hi @Szabolcs Thanks a lot for the explanation. I think I didn't completely understand this at that point in time. I'd like to know if there is a way to check this beforehand. Would it suffice to check this condition for the edges that form a triangle before the optimization step? Your inputs will be highly useful

Comment: @Szabolcs The other mismatches occur for edges : (22,23), (23,31), (22,28), (25,28). However, these don't form a triangle and I am not sure what could be the problem here.

Comment: "Would it suffice to check this condition for the edges that form a triangle before the optimization step?" No, that would not be sufficient, but I don't know what a sufficient set of conditions are for this problem.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks for the response. For now, I'd like to print the edges for which edge length is not equal to edge weights. Could you please suggest how to print that as output?

Comment: It is much much faster to use methods from dimension reduction, in the case when all distances are known. So use an all-pairs-shortest-paths to get the pair-wise distance matrix. Then crib code from e.g. `ResourceFunction["MultidimensionalScaling"]` to relocate the vertices in R^2. If you are dead set on using a different optimization, go with `FindMinimum` over `Minimize`.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thank you. Yes, all distances are known. Could you please elaborate a bit on ` use an all-pairs-shortest-paths to get the pair-wise distance matrix. Then crib code from e.g. ResourceFunction["MultidimensionalScaling"] to relocate the vertices in R^2.`?

Comment: (1) Your graph edges give distances between immediate neighbors. A distance matrix requires distances between all pairs of vertices. All-pairs-shortest-paths is a way to get that full set of pairwise distances. The function `GraphDistanceMatrix` can be used for this purpose.

Comment: (2) Get the definition notebook from [the page form MultidimensionalScaling](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MultidimensionalScaling). Modify to use your distance matrix instead of computing one based on vector coordinates.

Answer (score 6):

Having taken the time to check details on how to do this, I guess I should show it.

We start with the graph.

```
edges = {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 
   1 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 
   2 \[UndirectedEdge] 6, 5 \[UndirectedEdge] 6, 
   3 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 7, 
   6 \[UndirectedEdge] 7, 7 \[UndirectedEdge] 8, 
   2 \[UndirectedEdge] 9};
verts = Union[Flatten[edges /. UndirectedEdge -> List]];
ew = {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2 -> 49.6, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 3 -> 74.4, 
   1 \[UndirectedEdge] 4 -> 49.6, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 5 -> 37.2, 
   2 \[UndirectedEdge] 6 -> 74.4, 5 \[UndirectedEdge] 6 -> 49.6, 
   3 \[UndirectedEdge] 4 -> 37.2, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 7 -> 24.8, 
   6 \[UndirectedEdge] 7 -> 62, 7 \[UndirectedEdge] 8 -> 37.2, 
   2 \[UndirectedEdge] 9 -> 24.8};
graph = Graph[verts, edges, EdgeWeight -> ew, 
  VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
  EdgeLabels -> {e_ :> Placed["EdgeWeight", Center]}, 
  VertexSize -> .3, VertexStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

This is not dreadful, as automatic layouts go. And one can improve "by eye" (I do not know why the automated method falls short here). Instead I'll show what I had in mind using multidimensional scaling.

Now we compute the distance matrix.

```
dmat = GraphDistanceMatrix[graph]

(* Out[1682]= {{0., 49.6, 74.4, 49.6, 86.8, 124., 99.2, 136.4, 
  74.4}, {49.6, 0., 124., 99.2, 37.2, 74.4, 136.4, 173.6, 
  24.8}, {74.4, 124., 0., 37.2, 136.4, 86.8, 24.8, 62., 148.8}, {49.6,
   99.2, 37.2, 0., 136.4, 124., 62., 99.2, 124.}, {86.8, 37.2, 136.4, 
  136.4, 0., 49.6, 111.6, 148.8, 62.}, {124., 74.4, 86.8, 124., 49.6, 
  0., 62., 99.2, 99.2}, {99.2, 136.4, 24.8, 62., 111.6, 62., 0., 37.2,
   161.2}, {136.4, 173.6, 62., 99.2, 148.8, 99.2, 37.2, 0., 
  198.4}, {74.4, 24.8, 148.8, 124., 62., 99.2, 161.2, 198.4, 0.}} *)
```

Here is what I had in mind for modifying implementation code of `ResourceFunction["MultidimensionalScaling"]`.

```
DistanceMatrixDimensionReduce[(dmat_)?MatrixQ, dim_ : 2] := 
 With[{len = Length[dmat]}, 
  Module[{diffs, dist2mat, onevec, hmat, bmat, uu, ww, vv}, 
    onevec = ConstantArray[{1}, len]; 
    hmat = IdentityMatrix[len] - onevec . Transpose[onevec]/len;  
    dist2mat = -dmat/2; 
    bmat = hmat . dist2mat . hmat; {uu, ww, vv} = 
     SingularValueDecomposition[bmat, dim]; uu . Sqrt[ww]] /; 
   dim <= Length[dmat[[1]]] && MatchQ[Flatten[dmat], {_Real ..}]]
```

We use this to obtain new vertex coordinates for the graph.

```
newcoords = DistanceMatrixDimensionReduce[dmat]

(* Out[1675]= {{-1.67377, 4.63647}, {-5.6866, 0.575728},
  {4.71118, 1.7079}, {2.55599, 4.83333}, {-4.47255, -3.45886},
  {-0.471663, -5.30871}, {5.16612, -1.4306},
  {6.39076, -2.33059}, {-6.51947, 0.775332}} *)
```

Now show the new layout.

```
newLayout = 
 Graph[verts, edges, VertexCoordinates -> newcoords, EdgeWeight -> ew, 
  VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
  EdgeLabels -> {e_ :> Placed["EdgeWeight", Center]}, 
  VertexSize -> .3, VertexStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

Can one do better than this? Almost certainly. This method is overly constrained in that it needs all pairwise distances, and it treats them as Euclidean when an actual graph treats them as piecewise Euclidean. So optimizing a sum-of-squares-of-discrepancies will be less constrained. But it might be slow, at least for large graphs.

--- edit ---

Here is a nice way to get a better layout (perfect, in this example). We start from the layout we obtained above and use that to do a local optimization with `FindMinumum`. For this we require variables to use for the vertex coordinates, and we need the distances to immediate neighbors.

```
vars = Array[xy, {Length[verts], 2}];
weights = Normal[WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[graph]]

(* Out[1718]= {{0, 49.6, 74.4, 49.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {49.6, 0, 0, 0, 
  37.2, 74.4, 0, 0, 24.8}, {74.4, 0, 0, 37.2, 0, 0, 24.8, 0, 
  0}, {49.6, 0, 37.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 37.2, 0, 0, 0, 49.6, 0, 
  0, 0}, {0, 74.4, 0, 0, 49.6, 0, 62, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 24.8, 0, 0, 62, 0,
   37.2, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 37.2, 0, 0}, {0, 24.8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0}} *)
```

Now we create the objective as a sum of squares of discrepancies between symbolic variable distances and graph distances. I use squared distances here to avoid square roots.

```
objective = 
 Sum[If[weights[[i, j]] > 
    0, ((vars[[i]] - vars[[j]]).(vars[[i]] - vars[[j]]) - 
      weights[[i, j]]^2)^2, 0], {i, Length[weights] - 1}, {j, i + 1, 
   Length[weights]}]

(* Out[1751]= (-2460.16 + (xy[1, 1] - xy[2, 1])^2 + (xy[1, 2] - 
     xy[2, 2])^2)^2 + (-5535.36 + (xy[1, 1] - 
     xy[3, 1])^2 + (xy[1, 2] - 
     xy[3, 2])^2)^2 + (-2460.16 + (xy[1, 1] - 
     xy[4, 1])^2 + (xy[1, 2] - 
     xy[4, 2])^2)^2 + (-1383.84 + (xy[3, 1] - 
     xy[4, 1])^2 + (xy[3, 2] - 
     xy[4, 2])^2)^2 + (-1383.84 + (xy[2, 1] - 
     xy[5, 1])^2 + (xy[2, 2] - 
     xy[5, 2])^2)^2 + (-5535.36 + (xy[2, 1] - 
     xy[6, 1])^2 + (xy[2, 2] - 
     xy[6, 2])^2)^2 + (-2460.16 + (xy[5, 1] - 
     xy[6, 1])^2 + (xy[5, 2] - xy[6, 2])^2)^2 + (-615.04 + (xy[3, 1] -
      xy[7, 1])^2 + (xy[3, 2] - xy[7, 2])^2)^2 + (-3844 + (xy[6, 1] - 
     xy[7, 1])^2 + (xy[6, 2] - 
     xy[7, 2])^2)^2 + (-1383.84 + (xy[7, 1] - 
     xy[8, 1])^2 + (xy[7, 2] - xy[8, 2])^2)^2 + (-615.04 + (xy[2, 1] -
      xy[9, 1])^2 + (xy[2, 2] - xy[9, 2])^2)^2 *)
```

Optimize this.

```
{min, vals} = 
 FindMinimum[objective, 
  Flatten[MapThread[List, {vars, newcoords}, 2], 1]]

(* Out[1761]= {1.4853*10^-24, {xy[1, 1] -> -23.2827, xy[1, 2] -> 42.3923,
   xy[2, 1] -> -42.4665, xy[2, 2] -> -3.34769, xy[3, 1] -> 25.6614, 
  xy[3, 2] -> -13.6419, xy[4, 1] -> 22.5485, xy[4, 2] -> 23.4276, 
  xy[5, 1] -> -5.29537, xy[5, 2] -> -4.81353, xy[6, 1] -> 15.6832, 
  xy[6, 2] -> -49.7586, xy[7, 1] -> 27.6269, xy[7, 2] -> 11.0801, 
  xy[8, 1] -> 0.512013, xy[8, 2] -> -14.388, xy[9, 1] -> -20.9875, 
  xy[9, 2] -> 9.04959}} *)
```

Use this to create the new layout.

```
newercoords = vars /. vals;
vcoords3 = MapIndexed[#2[[1]] -> # &, newercoords];
newLayout = 
 Graph[verts, edges, VertexCoordinates -> vcoords3, EdgeWeight -> ew, 
  VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
  EdgeLabels -> {e_ :> Placed["EdgeWeight", Center]}, 
  VertexSize -> .3, VertexStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

Not terribly pretty but it seems to respect the distance requirements. One can obtain different solutions by specifying a `Method` option to `FindMinimum`. (For reasons unknown to me, `"LevenbergMarquardt"` balks at this objective function. It wants an explicit sum of squares. Whhich I gave it. Go figure.)

Actual graph layout functions tend to add penalties to move vertices apart, so one might in principle get a better looking layout while still satisfying the distance requirements. Offhand I am not familiar with the specifics. Roughly, one such method applies a spring-like force in its penalty function. This is getting outside of my expertise and also a bit beyond the question that was asked.

--- end edit ---

Comment: Thanks a ton. I'll look through the code to understand the implementation, test on other graphs, and get back to you if I have doubts:)

Comment: `weights = Normal[WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[graph]]` instead of `weights = Normal[WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[gr]]`

Comment: @SteffenJaeschke Thanks, now fixed. I also see there are one or two other error which I will fix when I get back to my "real" computer.

Comment: The distances can not be matched complete. A match can be approximized. This is what the first 2d solution already does. The optimization function of the LevenbergMarquardt have to be given an orientation, inner and outer. That is fairly complex. Idea can be found in [https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42304/finding-the-intersection-of-a-curve-with-an-interpolation-function/42310#42310] -> NoCrossings option.

Comment: @SteffenJaeschke (1) The `FindMinimum` residual of 10^(-24) or so means it found a solution that satisfies all constraints to numerical precision. So it gave what you refer to as a complete match. (2) LevenbergMarquardt requires a sum of squares. Which is what I gave it.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau In the version of the code that was posted in my original post, the squared error distances between the user-defined 3D coordinates and the new coordinates obtained after optimization was minimized. In the version posted above, if my understanding is right the user-defined coordinates aren't taken into account ; the `new_coordinates` returns the coordinates in 2D I'm not sure how this will work if the coordinates are required in 3D. Could you please explain this a bit?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I made a few changes to adapt your code for 3D and tested for a large graph. The layout obtained in the end doesn't look good and unfortunately the minimization failed. I am sharing the notebook [here](https://github.com/DeepaMahm/misc/blob/master/check4.nb). Could you please have a look?

Comment: (1) for 3D, just use 3 when calling the dimension reduction. Likewise for defining the variables, if you also do that minimization. (2) the minimization will not do a good job with vertex pairs that are not connected by an edge. You might want to add constraints that such pairs have some minimum separation, perhaps a fraction of their (multiple edge) graph distance.

Comment: @Natasha The shared nb is around 8000 lines that, as best I can tell, I would have to copy/paste and with no way to select only the code. So realistically I cannot figure out how to look at it. I will suggest saving the code part in a .m file instead, or editing your original question to show what you tried in that notebook.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau The notebook can be downloaded by clicking on the icon `Raw` and Ctrl + S :) In case the download doesn't work could you please download the file from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pqAMFs-y0mmDzwhKLnL1Ox12myx7CclL/view?usp=sharing). I tried the same on another large network and this didn't work too [notebook](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11Rpwe-PWAYYRsTmmwyXtvNjDKM0pxN_h/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: (1) Change `vcoords2` to `newcoords`. The former was a hold-over from earlier code that I forgot to update. (2) I suspect the minimization residual of around 10^7 is as good as can be obtained. I got it using at least three distinct `Method` option settings. This larger graph may well not have a layout respecting edge weights in 3D.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thank you, I made the change and I could observe a value of 10^7 using FindMinimum. Could you please suggest what are the method options that I can try other than FindMinimum and how this line `{min, vals} = 
 Minimize[objective, 
  Flatten[MapThread[List, {vars, newcoords}, 2], 1]]` has to be changed accordingly? I simply replaced FindMinimum with Minimize that doesn't seem to work though

Comment: "This larger graph may well not have a layout respecting edge weights in 3D" Could you please check my edit in the original post?

Comment: You can use `FindMinimum` the way I used it in my response. For methods I used `"Newton"`, `"QuasiNewton"` and I think `"PrincipalAxes"`. `"LevenbergMarquardt"` failed and `"InteriorPoint"` crashed, so those were both discouraging. That latter might have required large dense matrices though, so maybe a memory limitation was surpassed.The LM method failure might be worth reporting as a bug.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thank you. For the large graph in [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1F6zKJQOwWhA57MPOqJEBWhh0DvXII2fz/view?usp=sharing) notebook, "Netwon" returned an error `The computation encountered machine-number overflow` , "PrincipleAxes"  and "QuasiNetwon"returned an error:  `FindMinimum::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations.` Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find an answer to the problem stated in the EDIT yet.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau In the original post, line `Grid[Prepend[{#, # /. ew, # /. edgeLengths3d} & /@ 
   EdgeList[g3d], {"edge", "EdgeWeight", "Edge Length"}], 
 Dividers -> All]` helps in creating  a table edge length and edge weights for each edge.  Could you please help me with adding a similar table in your response? This will help me in identifiying mismatches.

Comment: I'm not sure what is needed for the grid. Guessing you will want to compute edge lengths in the 3D embedding of the graph? If so, that can be done from the distances between vertex coordinates e.g. in what I called `newercoords`.

Answer (score 2):

To me this appears to be a nice result:

```
DynamicModule[{acc, new, newEdg, newNodes, newPos, newInd}, 
 Grid[{{LocatorPane[Dynamic@newPos, 
     Dynamic[Graph[Map[f12, node~Join~newNodes], edges, 
       VertexCoordinates -> (vertexposition~Join~newPos), 
       VertexLabels -> "Name", 
       VertexSize -> {Sequence @@ 
          Thread[node -> 
            Table[{"Scaled", .05}, {Length@
               vertexposition}]], {"Scaled", .02}}, ImageSize -> 600, 
       EdgeShapeFunction -> {Arrow[#, 2] &}, 
       VertexLabelStyle -> {Bold, 20}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
       Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> All, 
       PlotRange -> {{-5, 120}, {-5, 65}}]], Appearance -> None], 
    Column[{Checkbox[Dynamic@loc], 
      If[loc, "Locators on", "Locators off"]}]}}], 
 Initialization :> (new = {}; acc = {}; newNodes = {}; newPos = {}; 
   loc = False;
   f12 := 
    If[loc, #, 
      Style[Button[#, 
        Which[acc == {#}, acc = {}, Length@acc == 1, 
         AppendTo[acc, #];
         AppendTo[newPos, 
          Mean[Pick[(vertexposition~Join~newPos), (node~Join~
                 newNodes), #][[1]] & /@ acc]];
         newInd = Last[node~Join~newNodes] + 1;
         AppendTo[newNodes, newInd];
         edges = DeleteCases[edges, Rule @@ acc];
         AppendTo[edges, #] & /@ {First@acc -> newInd, 
           newInd -> Last@acc};
         acc = {};, True, acc = {#}]], 
       If[MemberQ[acc, #], Red, Blue]]] &;
   node = {11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19};
   edges = {11 -> 12, 11 -> 13, 11 -> 14, 12 -> 15, 12 -> 16, 
     15 -> 16, 13 -> 14, 13 -> 17, 16 -> 17, 17 -> 18, 12 -> 19};
   vertexposition = {{75., 25.}, {115., 45.}, {10., 5.}, {45., 
      0.}, {90., 60.}, {45., 55.}, {0., 25.}, {10., 50.}, {115., 
      25.}};)]
```

[image: Graph with Frame, Frameticks, PlotRange]

It seems there is a hidden option in `Graph` working with the options `Frame`, `FrameTicks`, `PlotRange` giving the desired result. I have difficulties in describing the transformation used by Graph if the edge weights are used. This is based in addition to the aforementioned solely on node, edges and vertexpositions corresponding one-to-one on vd without the z-component.

Hope that does the deal of the question.