# Issue while evaluating Mathematica expressions from Python

Tags: graphs-and-networks, mathematical-optimization, python, wolfram-client

This is a follow up to my question posted [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230523/optimizing-the-edge-lengths-of-a-graph)
I am  trying to run the code posted [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/230741/58343) as an answer in the above-mentioned link  here from Python

I tried,

```
from wolframclient.evaluation import WolframLanguageSession
from wolframclient.language import wl, wlexpr, Global

edges = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (5, 6), (3, 4), (3, 7), (6, 7), (7, 8), (2, 9)]
ew = {(1, 2): 49.6, (1, 3): 74.4, (1, 4): 49.6, (2, 5): 37.2, (2, 6): 74.4, (5, 6): 49.6, (3, 4): 37.2, (3, 7): 24.8, (6, 7): 62, (7, 8): 37.2, (2, 9): 24.8}
with WolframLanguageSession() as s:
     s.evaluate(wl.Get('wolfram_input.m'))
     s.evaluate(Global.solution3d(edges, ew))
```

wolfram_input.m contains Mathematica expressions

```
solution3d[uedges_, edgeweight_] := Module[{
   edges = UndirectedEdge @@@ uedges;
   ew = KeyMap[UndirectedEdge @@ # &, edgeweight];

   verts, graph, dmat, hmat, dist2mat, bmat, dim, newcoords, newLayout, EdgeLabels, VertexSize, vars, weights, objective,
   min, vals, newercoords},

   verts = Union[Flatten[edges /. UndirectedEdge -> List]];

   graph = Graph3D[verts, edges, EdgeWeight -> ew, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center],
           EdgeLabels -> {e_ :> Placed["EdgeWeight", Center]}, VertexSize -> .3, VertexStyle -> Red];

   dmat = GraphDistanceMatrix[graph];
   DistanceMatrixDimensionReduce[(dmat_)?MatrixQ, dim_: 3] :=
    With[{len = Length[dmat]},
    Module[{diffs, dist2mat, onevec, hmat, bmat, uu, ww, vv},
    onevec = ConstantArray[{1}, len];

    hmat = IdentityMatrix[len] - onevec.Transpose[onevec]/len;

    dist2mat = -dmat/2;

    bmat = hmat.dist2mat.hmat; {uu, ww, vv} =
    SingularValueDecomposition[bmat, dim]; uu.Sqrt[ww]] /;

    dim <= Length[dmat[[1]]] && MatchQ[Flatten[dmat], {_Real ..}]];

    newcoords = DistanceMatrixDimensionReduce[dmat];

    newLayout = Graph[verts, edges, VertexCoordinates -> vcoords2, EdgeWeight -> ew,
    VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center];

    EdgeLabels -> {e_ :> Placed["EdgeWeight", Center]};

    VertexSize -> .3, VertexStyle -> Red];

    vars = Array[xyz, {Length[verts], 3}];

    weights = Normal[WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[graph]];

    objective =
    Sum[If[weights[[i, j]] >
    0, ((vars[[i]] - vars[[j]]).(vars[[i]] - vars[[j]]) -
    weights[[i, j]]^2)^2, 0], {i, Length[weights] - 1}, {j, i + 1,
    Length[weights]}];

   {min, vals} =
   FindMinimum[objective,
   Flatten[MapThread[List, {vars, newcoords}, 2], 1]];
   Print[min];
   newercoords = vars /. vals;
]
```

I think there is a problem with the local variable specification.

```
    Local variable specification {CompoundExpression[Set[edges, Apply[UndirectedEdge, {{1, 2}, {1, 3},
 {1, 4}, {2, 5}, {2, 6}, {5, 6}, {3, 4}, {3, 7}, {6, 7}, {7, 8}, {2, 9}}, {1}]], Set[ew, 
KeyMap[Function[Apply[UndirectedEdge, Slot[1]]], Association[{{1, 2} -> 49.6, {1, 3} -> 74.4, {1, 4} -> 
49.6, {2, 5} -> 37.2, {2, 6} -> 74.4, {5, 6} -> 49.6, {3, 4} -> 37.2, {3, 7} -> 24.8, {6, 7} -> 62, {7, 
8} -> 37.2, {2, 9} -> 24.8}]]], verts], graph, dmat, hmat, dist2mat, bmat, dim, newcoords, newLayout, 
EdgeLabels, VertexSize, vars, weights, objective, min, vals, newercoords} contains 
CompoundExpression[Set[edges, Apply[UndirectedEdge, {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 5}, {2, 6}, {5, 6}, {3, 
4}, {3, 7}, {6, 7}, {7, 8}, {2, 9}}, {1}]], Set[ew, KeyMap[Function[Apply[UndirectedEdge, Slot[1]]],
 Association[{{1, 2} -> 49.6, {1, 3} -> 74.4, {1, 4} -> 49.6, {2, 5} -> 37.2, {2, 6} -> 74.4, {5, 6} -> 
49.6, {3, 4} -> 37.2, {3, 7} -> 24.8, {6, 7} -> 62, {7, 8} -> 37.2, {2, 9} -> 24.8}]]], verts], which is 
not a symbol or an assignment to a symbol.
```

Could someone help me with this?

EDIT:

```
solution3d[uedges_, edgeweight_] := Module[{
   edges = UndirectedEdge @@@ uedges,
          ew = KeyMap[UndirectedEdge @@ # &, edgeweight],
   verts = Union[Flatten[edges /. UndirectedEdge -> List]],
   graph, dmat, newcoords, vcoords3, newLayout, vars, weights, 
   objective, min, vals, newercoords, xyz},
  
        graph = 
   Graph3D[verts, edges, EdgeWeight -> ew, 
    VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
    EdgeLabels -> {e_ :> Placed["EdgeWeight", Center]}, 
    VertexSize -> .3, VertexStyle -> Red];
   dmat = GraphDistanceMatrix[graph];
   DistanceMatrixDimensionReduce[(dmat_)?MatrixQ, dim_: 3] := 
   With[{len = Length[dmat]}, 
    Module[{diffs, dist2mat, onevec, hmat, bmat, uu, ww, vv}, 
      onevec = ConstantArray[{1}, len];
      hmat = IdentityMatrix[len] - onevec.Transpose[onevec]/len;
      dist2mat = -dmat/2;
      bmat = hmat.dist2mat.hmat; {uu, ww, vv} = 
       SingularValueDecomposition[bmat, dim]; uu.Sqrt[ww]] /; 
     dim <= Length[dmat[[1]]] && MatchQ[Flatten[dmat], {_Real ..}]];
  newcoords = DistanceMatrixDimensionReduce[dmat];
  newLayout = 
   Graph[verts, edges, VertexCoordinates -> newcoords, 
    EdgeWeight -> ew, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
    EdgeLabels -> {e_ :> Placed["EdgeWeight", Center]}, 
    VertexSize -> .3, VertexStyle -> Red];
  vars = Array[xyz, {Length[verts], 3}];
  weights = Normal[WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[graph]];
  objective = 
   Sum[If[weights[[i, j]] > 
      0, ((vars[[i]] - vars[[j]]).(vars[[i]] - vars[[j]]) - 
        weights[[i, j]]^2)^2, 0], {i, Length[weights] - 1}, {j, i + 1,
      Length[weights]}];
  
  {min, vals} = 
   FindMinimum[objective, 
    Flatten[MapThread[List, {vars, newcoords}, 2], 1]];
  newercoords = vars /. vals;
      vcoords3 = MapIndexed[#2[[1]] -> # &, newercoords];
      newLayout = 
   Graph3D[verts, edges, VertexCoordinates -> vcoords3, 
    EdgeWeight -> ew, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
    EdgeLabels -> {e_ :> Placed["EdgeWeight", Center]}, 
    VertexSize -> .3, VertexStyle -> Red];
  Return[<|"newcoords" -> newcoords|>];
  ]
```

I have tried to correct the syntax errors in the code. But the run is not successful yet. I have added the output logs [here](https://github.com/DeepaMahm/misc/blob/master/out.txt).

I look forward to suggestions that will help me in resolving these errors.

Comment: `Print(min)` at the end - you need `Print[min];` (a semicolon and square brackets are both necessary).

Comment: @flinty I made the change and the same message is still displayed

Comment: No semi-colons in `Module` variable specifications, e.g. the variable here: `edges = UndirectedEdge @@@ uedges;`

Comment: ^ yes b3m2a1 is right - you  need commas. You should really review your syntax and paste your code into a mathematica notebook to look at the syntax highlighting - it has all kinds of errors.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Thank you. Please check my edit

Comment: @flinty Thank you. Please check my edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have re-written your code with as few changes as possible just to make it work:

```
Clear[solution3d];
solution3d[uedges_, edgeweight_] := 
 Module[{ew, graph, dmat, newcoords, vcoords3, newLayout, vars, 
   weights, objective, min, vals, newercoords, xyz, 
   DistanceMatrixDimensionReduce},
  ew = KeyMap[UndirectedEdge @@ # &, edgeweight];
  graph = 
   Graph3D[Keys[ew], EdgeWeight -> Normal[ew], 
    VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
    EdgeLabels -> {e_ :> Placed["EdgeWeight", Center]}, 
    VertexSize -> .3, VertexStyle -> Red];
  dmat = GraphDistanceMatrix[graph];
  DistanceMatrixDimensionReduce[(dmat_)?MatrixQ, dim_ : 3] := 
   With[{len = Length[dmat]}, 
    Module[{diffs, dist2mat, onevec, hmat, bmat, uu, ww, vv}, 
      onevec = ConstantArray[{1}, len];
      hmat = IdentityMatrix[len] - onevec.Transpose[onevec]/len;
      dist2mat = -dmat/2;
      bmat = hmat.dist2mat.hmat; {uu, ww, vv} = 
       SingularValueDecomposition[bmat, dim]; uu.Sqrt[ww]] /; 
     dim <= Length[dmat[[1]]] && MatchQ[Flatten[dmat], {_Real ..}]];
  newcoords = DistanceMatrixDimensionReduce[dmat];
  newLayout = 
   Graph[Keys[ew], VertexCoordinates -> newcoords, EdgeWeight -> ew, 
    VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
    EdgeLabels -> {e_ :> Placed["EdgeWeight", Center]}, 
    VertexSize -> .3, VertexStyle -> Red];
  vars = Array[xyz, {VertexCount[graph], 3}];
  weights = Normal[WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[graph]];
  objective = 
   Sum[If[weights[[i, j]] > 
      0, ((vars[[i]] - vars[[j]]).(vars[[i]] - vars[[j]]) - 
        weights[[i, j]]^2)^2, 0], {i, Length[weights] - 1}, {j, i + 1,
      Length[weights]}];
  {min, vals} = Quiet@FindMinimum[objective, 
    Flatten[MapThread[List, {vars, newcoords}, 2], 1]];
  newercoords = vars /. vals;
  vcoords3 = MapIndexed[#2[[1]] -> # &, newercoords];
  newLayout = 
   Graph3D[Keys[ew], VertexCoordinates -> vcoords3, EdgeWeight -> ew, 
    VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
    EdgeLabels -> {e_ :> Placed["EdgeWeight", Center]}, 
    VertexSize -> .3, VertexStyle -> Red];
  Return[<|"newcoords" -> newcoords|>]]



(* test it out: *)
edges = {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 5}, {2, 6}, {5, 6}, {3, 4}, {3, 7}, {6, 7}, {7, 8}, {2, 9}};
ew = <|{1, 2} -> 49.6, {1, 3} -> 74.4, {1, 4} -> 49.6, {2, 5} -> 
    37.2, {2, 6} -> 74.4, {5, 6} -> 49.6, {3, 4} -> 37.2, {3, 7} -> 
    24.8, {6, 7} -> 62, {7, 8} -> 37.2, {2, 9} -> 24.8|>;

solution3d[edges, ew]

(** result: 
<|"newcoords" -> {{-1.67377, 4.63647, 1.37539}, {-5.6866, 0.575728, 
    0.0714674}, {4.71118, 1.7079, -2.10904}, {2.55599, 
    4.83333, -1.12337}, {-4.47255, -3.45886, 
    0.799296}, {-0.471663, -5.30871, -2.43743}, {5.16612, -1.4306, \
-0.875186}, {6.39076, -2.33059, 3.91076}, {-6.51947, 0.775332, 
    0.388113}}|> 
**)
```

You are constructing graphs with presentational elements like labels and styling, but this is kind of pointless if you are only returning `newcoords`. You should consider removing all those unused styling properties. You also need to print the return value of `s.evaluate(Global.solution3d(edges, ew))` in Python to see any output, so that you get:

```
{'newcoords': PackedArray([[-1.67377155,  4.63646567,  1.37539104],
             [-5.68660341,  0.57572758,  0.0714674 ],
             [ 4.71118143,  1.70789586, -2.10903571],
             [ 2.55599235,  4.83333027, -1.12337187],
             [-4.47254779, -3.45885521,  0.79929634],
             [-0.47166292, -5.30870618, -2.43743431],
             [ 5.16612254, -1.43059762, -0.87518615],
             [ 6.39076194, -2.33059232,  3.91075979],
             [-6.51947259,  0.77533196,  0.38811348]])}
```